# C++ file stream open modes ambiguity

Tags: c++, file-io, stream

For performing file IO in C++ we use the ofstream, ifstream and fstream classes.

- ofstream: Stream class to write on files
- ifstream: Stream class to read from files
- fstream: Stream class to both read and write from/to files

The process of associating a file with a stream object is called "opening the file".
When opening a file we can specify the mode in which the file is to be opened.
My query is related to the `ios::out` and `ios:in` modes.

When I create an `ofstream` object and open the file with `ios::in` mode, I am able to
write into the file but only if its created already(with `ios::out` mode file is also created if it doesn't already exist). 
 
But when I create `ifstream` object and open the file with `ios::out` mode, I am able to read from the file.

My question is why these modes (`ios::in`/`ios::out`) are supplied by the language when the type of the stream(`ifstream`/`ofstream`) itself specifies as to which type of operation(input/output) is being performed ?

Also why this ambiguous usage(`ofstream` with `ios::in` and `ifstream` with `ios::out`) works in one case and fails(though only if file is not already present) in another ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `ofstream`, `ifstream` and `fstream` classes are high level interfaces for the underlying `filebuf`, which one can access through the `rdbuf()` member function of the stream.

When you open an `ofstream` with some mode `mode`, it opens the underlying stream buffer with `mode | ios_base::out`. Analogously `ifstream` uses `mode | ios_base::in`. `fstream` passes the `mode` parameter verbatim to the underlying stream buffer.

What the above implies is that the following code opens the file with exactly the same open flags:

```
fstream f("a.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
ifstream g("a.txt", ios_base::out);
ofstream h("a.txt", ios_base::in);
```

After these lines you can do exactly the same things with `f.rdbuf()`, `g.rdbuf()` and `h.rdbuf()`, and all the three act as if you opened the file with the C call `fopen("a.txt", "r+")`, which gives you read/write access, does not truncate the file, and fails if the file does not exist.

So, why do we have three different classes? As previously stated, these are high level classes providing a high-level interface over the lower-level stream buffer. The idea is that `ifstream` has member functions for input (like `read()`), `ofstream` has member functions for output (like `write()`) while `fstream` has both. For example you cannot do this:

```
g.write("abc", 3); // error: g does not have a write function
```

But this works, because, although `g` is an `ifstream`, we opened it with `ios_base::out`:

```
g.rdbuf()->sputn("abc", 3); // we still have write access
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the mode is not limited to input/output. The constructor of `ifstream`, for example, looks like:

```
explicit ifstream ( const char * filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

Note the default value is `ios_base::in`, so you don't have to specify it yourself. However, the `mode` sets the streams flags which are **not** limited to `in`/`out`, but include:

- `app` (append) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream before each output operation.
- `ate` (at end) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream on opening.
- `binary`  (binary) Consider stream as binary rather than text.
- `in`  (input) Allow input operations on the stream.
- `out` (output) Allow output operations on the stream.
- `trunc`   (truncate) Any current content is discarded, assuming a length of zero on opening.