# Default mode of fstream

Tags: c++, file-handling, tdm-gcc

I was looking at the SO post [C++ file stream open modes ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365218/c-file-stream-open-modes-ambiguity). I wanted to know the default file opening mode of fstream. One of the answer says,

> What the above implies is that the following code opens the file with
>   exactly the same open flags fstream f("a.txt", ios_base::in |
>   ios_base::out); ifstream g("a.txt", ios_base::out); ofstream
>   h("a.txt", ios_base::in);

So if I understand correctly, in case I create object of fstream, I should be able to either read or write.

But below code does not write any data to file

```
fstream testFile1;
testFile1.open("text1.txt");
testFile1<<"Writing data to file";
testFile1.close();
```

However adding mode as given below creates text file with data "Writing data to file"

```
testFile1.open("text1.txt", ios::out);
```

So whether the default mode is implementation defined? I am using TDM-GCC-64 toolchain.

Comment: The mode `ios::in`, as well as `ios::in | ios::out`, requires that the file already exists. Otherwise `open` will fail - which you forgot to check...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default mode of `ifstream` is `in`. The default mode of `ofstream` is `out`. That's why they're named that way. `fstream` has **no** default mode.

Your example only shows the two defaults, and it shows that by omission of explicit arguments. That `fstream f("a.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out)` uses two explicit arguments is precisely because there is no default mode.

Comment: This is plainly wrong; the default is `in|out`. If you've default-constructed it, look at `open()` instead. ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open))

Answer (score 6):

The default mode for `std::fstream`s is `std::ios::in|std::ios::out`. ([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open))

The reason your code doesn't print anything to `test1.txt` is that the `std::ios::in|std::ios::out` mode does not create the file if it does not already exist ([Source: table on this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)).

You can use the `std::ios::in|std::ios::app` mode, which will start reading from the start, will start writing from the end, and will create the file if it does not exist. Note that using `app` mode, the file will seek to the end before each write ([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)).